# Perl - Parsing Arguments/Options with REGEX

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, arguments

I'm creating a perl script to convert a list of commands in a template file () and output them to another file in a different format in an output file ().

The commands in the template file will look as follows:

```
command1 --max-size=2M --type="some value"
```

I'm having some problems extracting the options and values from this string. So far i have:

```
m/(\s--\w*=)/ig
```

Which will return:

```
" --max-size="
" --type="
```

However I have no idea how to return both the option and value as a separate variable or how to accommodate for the use of quotes.

Could anyone steer me in the right direction?

*side note: I'm aware that Getops does an awesome job at doing this from the command-line but unfortunately these commands are passed as strings :(*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below produces

```
@args = ('command1', '--max-size=2M', '--type=some value');
```

That is suitable to pass to `GetOptions` as follows:

```
local @ARGV = @args;
GetOptions(...) or die;
```

Finally, the code:

```
for ($cmd) {
   my @args;
   while (1) {
      last if /\G \s* \z /xgc;

      /\G \s* /xgc;

      my $arg;
      while (1) {
         if (/\G ([^\\"'\s]) /xgc) {
            $arg .= $1;
         }
         elsif (/\G \\ /xgc) {
            /\G (.) /sxgc
               or die "Incomplete escape";

            $arg .= $1;
         }
         elsif (/\G (?=") /xgc) {
            /\G " ( (?:[^"\\]|\\.)* ) " /sxgc
               or die "Incomplete double-quoted arging";

            my $quoted = $1;
            $quoted =~ s/\\(.)/$1/sg;

            $arg .= $quoted;
         }
         elsif (/\G (?=') /xgc) {
            /\G ' ( [^']* ) ' /xgc
               or die "Incomplete single-quoted arging";

            $arg .= $1;
         }
         else {
            last;
         }
      }

      push @args, $arg;
   }

   @args
      or die "Blank command";

   ...
}
```

Comment: This solution **does not separate option from value** as requested by OP.

Comment: @Ωmega, Not only does it do separate the options from the values, it does a better job at it than all the other given solutions by actually using GetOptions to do it. Stop this harassing campaign.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up using GetOpt in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

[`Getopt::Std`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) or [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)?

Have you looked at [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Parsing-options-from-an-arbitrary-string) option or [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Parsing-options-from-an-arbitrary-array) one?

Seems like there's no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. I should have ready the getops docs more thoroughly as I totally overlooked the option to pass options from a string. This is ideal for what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Data::Dumper;
$_ = 'command1 --max-size=2M a=ignore =ignore --switch --type="some value" --x= --z=1';
my %args;
while (/((?<=\s--)[a-z\d-]+)(?:="?|(?=\s))((?<![="])|(?<=")[^"]*(?=")|(?<==)(?!")\S*(?!"))"?(?=\s|$)/ig) {
  $args->{$1} = $2;
}
print Dumper($args);

---

$VAR1 = {
          'switch' => '',
          'x' => '',
          'type' => 'some value',
          'z' => '1',
          'max-size' => '2M'
        };
```

(test this demo **[here](http://ideone.com/m1AlJy)**)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This has also helped me better understand REGEX.